# Extracted Regex Value not getting passed into next POST request body in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In my first request I am able to extract the value using Regular Expression Extractor which is clearly visible into the debug sampler. The value is extracted by setting the following options in Regular Expression Extractor:-

```
Name of Created Variable:- instanceUID 
Regular Expression:- "InstanceUid":"(.*?)"
Template:-$1$
Match No:-1
Default Value:- (Blank)
```

The value that I want to pass in the next POST request is visible as:-

```
instanceUID_g1=2ab5dfb8-a217-4ff2-9025-523565b7b7ad
```

And the body for the next HTTP POST request is set like this:-

```
${"iInfo":{"InstanceUid":"${instanceUID_g1}","Registry":"${Registry}"}}
```

When this request seen in detail inside View Results Tree looks like:-

```
${"iInfo":{"InstanceUid":"${instanceUID_g1}","Registry":"AAX"}}
```

As seen the value of `${instanceUID_g1}` did not get substituted in the POST body as was for variable `${Registry}` which was taken from CSV config.
Being new to Jmeter can anyone suggest what did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your Regular Expression Extractor placement is not very correct, be informed about [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) concept

- If you place Regular Expression Extractor as a child of the request - it will be applied to **this request only**

  [image]
- If you place Regular Expression Extractor at the same level as several requests - it will be applied **to all of them**

  [image]

in the latter case it will be applied 1st to 1st sampler, **then to Debug Sampler**, then to 3rd sampler so on 2nd step it will be overwritten, most probably that's your problem

Also it appears that you're getting the data from [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) so it makes more sense to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/)